# Jar bundler ANT task and working directory

Tags: macos, ant, jarbundler

There is a checkbox in **Jar Bundler** which allows to set working folder to *inside package*. Anybody knows how to do same thing using [JarBundler](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) ANT task? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it myself. Here's how:

```
<jarbundler dir="${deployment.dir}/bundled"
                name="qqq"
                mainclass="main.Main" 
            version="1.5"
            jvmversion="1.6+"
            icon="${deployment.dir}/Equals.icns"
                    workingdirectory="$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/Resources/Java">
```

Made a bundle and looked inside. There was a value "$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/Resources/Java". Jar Bundler uses it to set what i asked for. Thanks to those 9 people who at least read my question.